# Angular 4: Does service needs to be imported in component too?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am learning angular 4, I have registered my service in the provider's list of the app.module.ts.

Here is the code example:-

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FruitService } from './main/fruit.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
      FruitService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**fruit.service.ts**

```
export class FruitService {
    getFruits() {
        return ['apple', 'mango', 'banana'];
    }
}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
// import { FruitService } from './fruit.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    fruits;

  constructor(frts: FruitService) {
      this.fruits = frts.getFruits();
  }
}
```

The compiler emits the following error:-

```
Failed to compile.

/home/user/Projects/ng4app/src/app/app.component.ts (12,20): Cannot find name 'FruitService'.
```

However, I can't use the service without first importing it first into the component. Isn't it supposed to be available globally once it has been registered to the app.module?

Comment: The *service* is available for injection everywhere in the module, but you still need the import for the *token* / *name*, and its typings.

Answer (score 0):

You need it in the app.module, because of dependency injection. This however doesn't mean that you do not have to import it in every component.

Importing it into the app.module will make sure that **this** instance will be available globally for importing.